# Dictionary allKeys vs keyEnumerator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

Which to use when?

What if I am looping the dictionary and removing key-values from it, will the enumerator work for that? Documentation seem to answered that question:

> If you use this method with instances of mutable subclasses of
>   NSDictionary, your code should not modify the entries during
>   enumeration. If you intend to modify the entries, use the allKeys
>   property to create a “snapshot” of the dictionary’s keys. Then use
>   this snapshot to traverse the entries, modifying them along the way.

Performance?, because people always want to know.

Comment: `allKeys` creates a `NSArray` while `keyEnumerator` doesn't. So there is optimization done there. So if you have a lot of `keys` (and big ones, not only a simple `NSString`), prefers `keyEnumerator`. Else, devices are quite performant, and it shouldn't be a big issue for them (you may not notice the difference).

Comment: The size of individual objects in the array doesn't matter.  `NSArray` doesn't copy objects added to it, so the array returned by `allKeys` just has pointers to the original key objects.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration through `NSDictionary` could be achieved at least in two ways: using `NSArray` with `[NSDictionary allKeys]` or `NSEnumerator`.

```
NSArray *keyArray =  [bigUglyDictionary allKeys];
int count = [keyArray count];
for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
  NSDictionary *tmp = [bigUglyDictionary objectForKey:[ keyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [bigUglyDictionary keyEnumerator];
id key;
while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
  NSDictionary *tmp = [bigUglyDictionary objectForKey:key];
}
```

Second way is a little bit faster, so if you work with huge dictionaries and have no need of array with their keys